# Projective dimension of the residue field

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

For $R$ a ring and $M$ a module, denote the projective dimension of $M$ over $R$ by $\mathrm{pd}(M)$. We have the following:

*Lemma* (Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory, Section 19, Lemma 1). Let $(R,m,k)$ be a local ring and $M$ a finite (meaning finitely generated) $R$-module. Then $\mathrm{pd}_R(M) = \sup \{i \mid\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,k)\neq 0\}\leq \mathrm{pd}_R(k)$.

The first equation is clear from a proof that Matsumura gives, but I am really having a hard time seeing how $\mathrm{pd}_R(k)$ comes into the story. Matsumura does not seem to give any sort of argument for this (he does not give a lot of explanation for the first equation either, but at least that part is easy to see in context).

This lemma comes in (Matsumura's book) before Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem and Serre's characterization of RLR's (I think either of these make all of this obvious, but that would probably be circular). I know that $\mathrm{pd}_R(M)\leq \mathrm{pd}_R(k)$ is a very standard well-known result, but I have not yet found any sort of proof of it (only a bunch of pages stating how standard of a result it is).

(Yes, I know there are other MSE pages about this, I did not yet find one with a proof of this, of course.)

Comment: Read it this way: if $n>pd_R(k)$, then $Tor_n^R(M,k)=0$, which follows from the definition of Tor.